# Getting active TCP/UDP connections in c++ on linux

Tags: c++, linux, tcp

I am making program that require getting active TCP/UDP connections in c++ ? . I know that i can do  it on windows by using IP Helper API but i want to know that how to get active connections in C++ but on Linux . is using **popen()** function and **netstat** command a good selection or what ?  sorry for bad English :)

Comment: You haven't said what you mean by "getting" the connections - you want just a list of ports, or ports and pids, or to actually have control over them...?  Anyway, if `netstat` outputs what you want then well and good, `lsof` might be worth considering too....

Comment: @TonyD yes i want netstat output like this : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4298/Getting-active-TCP-UDP-connections-on-a-box

Comment: popen sounds fine then... might as well write the code then ask for suggestions if you have specific problems....

Comment: thank you , i will use popen function :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could read the following files:

- /proc/net/udp
- /proc/net/tcp

Content of those files are the following kind of text:

```
sl  local_address rem_address   st tx_queue rx_queue tr tm->when retrnsmt   uid  timeout inode
0: 00000000:5AA0 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 237373 1 cf0bc900 100 0 0 10 -1
1: 00000000:5AA1 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 237409 1 cf0be880 100 0 0 10 -1
2: 00000000:5AA2 00000000:0000 0A 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000     0        0 237435 1 cf0bdf80 100 0 0 10 -1
```

Man page `proc(5)` gives more information.

Comment: /proc/net  various net pseudo-files, all of which give the status of some part of the networking layer.  These files contain ASCII structures and are, therefore, readable with cat(1).  However, the standard netstat(8) suite provides much cleaner access to  these   files.

Comment: It is safe. And you can do it by using normal file reading functions like fopen/fscanf. 'cleaner access' means probably more human readable output, and clear command interface (instead of catting files).

Comment: thank you very much :) . reading this file is easier than using netstat

Answer (score 0):

To get the number of active connections openings, failed connection attempts, segments received, segments send out etc. netstat can be used

```
$ netstat -st
```

netstat in turn obtains this information from /proc/net/snmp. If you cannot rely on netstat being available on the DUT, you can read the values from  /proc/net/snmp programatically.